# Regex - how does Matcher.Group work

Tags: java, regex

Given the following regex and string

```
String regex = "Your fax has been successfully sent to (.*?)";
String val = "Your fax has been successfully sent to 123456789 at 123456789."
```

Now as far as i can see this matches, but if i call `Pattern.matcher(val).group(1)` then i get an index out of bound exception

Why would group 1 not be the

> 123456789 at 123456789?

Thanks

Comment: check it with the find function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Your fax has been successfully sent to (.*?)\.
```

Try this.Capture the groups.See demo.You did not use find as stated by others also you have not given capturing group a way to stop.You need to provide `.` for it to stop at `.` and capture rest.

http://regex101.com/r/uV3aL0/34

Comment: ahhh yes - i was using find (didnt paste it above my bad!) however the key was the \. that i was missing - thank you

Answer (score 1):

> Why would group 1 not be the [...]

Because you create the matcher but do not actually run it.

You need to `.find()` (and check the return value) before you can actually retrieve groups:

```
final Matcher matcher = yourPattern.matcher(val);
if (matcher.find())
    // use matcher.group(1)
```

Other alternatives: `.matches()`, `.findFirst()`.